# CSS responsive menu - right padding

Tags: css, menu, hover, responsive-design

I have responsive menu in middle of div.

After I resize screen menu moves to right of screen.

---

Preview example: [>>> CODE here <<<](http://mike.php5.sk/public/work/index.html) (all html/css/js are accessible via web)

it looks like this >

[image: before]

---

### Question:

How to **align it to right** as in picture ...

[image: after]

Thank you in advance.

PS: code is in example link (html file)

Comment: please read: >>> PS: code is in example link (html file), and why you adding negative points for that you cant read ?

Comment: The -1 is mine: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I created website example for better view, I have this on jsfiddle but if you resize screen you cant see output right, you know what is my problem ?

Comment: There should be code in your question and it should be reduced to the problem itself. Jsfiddle is not much better than a link to your website. Of course its ok as an addition to the code in your question.
The problem is if your website is down in the future, your question is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.content-menu`, and `position: absolute; right: 0;` to `.nav` (both in the mobile-size media query).

**EDIT** And also maybe remove the width on `.nav`, and `.nav > li` and change them to `max-width: 280px; min-width: 200px;` so that it won't break on screens smaller than 300px.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it work for me, but one thing, if I put .nav in DESKTOP view it will scru menu in desktop view. your asnwer is good, but delete that last (....) and will accept your answer, thank you

Comment: `.nav` doesnt need to be changed in mobile-size media query

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Put those bits of code in your `@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {` section and it will only affect screens smaller than 640px :)

Answer (score 2):

```
div.content-menu {
    position: relative;
}
ul.nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thx, but this is same as previous answer +1 for efford

Comment: yeah i saw, i was probably writing my answer in the same time, thx for +1

Comment: Yeah probs just at the same time :) Good answer.